# AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'manufacturer'

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

class Car:
def **init**(self, make, model, year):
self.make = make
self.model = model
self.year = year

```
def get_descriptive_name(self):
    #"Return a neatly formatted descriptive name.
    long_name = f"{self.year} {self.manufacturer} {self.model}"
    return long_name.title()
```

my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2019)
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())

Comment: How can the error message be any clearer? You don't have an attribute named `manufacturer`.

Comment: Format your code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self,make, model, year, manufacturer):
       self.make = make
       self.model = model
       self.year = year
       self.manufacturer = manufacturer
  def get_descriptive_name(self):
     long_name = f"{self.year} {self.manufacturer} {self.model}"
     return long_name.title()
```

Since you did not have manufacturer attribute it was throwing error
now you can make a object of class and pass values and call the function it should not through an error